# SwiftUI TabView and ScrollView gesture conflict

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a TabView which I made vertical by rotating, and a ScrollView inside it.

`VTabView` code sample [here](https://github.com/lorenzofiamingo/SwiftUI-VerticalTabView/blob/main/Sources/VTabView/VTabView.swift).

My `ContentView` is something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // Omitted properties
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VTabView(selection: $page) {
                FirstPageView()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    .tag(0)

                SecondPageView()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                    .tag(1)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}
```

And in my `SecondPageView`:

```
struct SecondPageView: View {
    // Omitted properties
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.compact.down")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.5))

                ScrollView {
                    // My ScrollView contents
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm on the second page and trying to scroll back to the first page, I can do it only outside the `ScrollView`'s bounds. If I scroll up in `ScrollView`'s bounds, it would stuck when `ScrollView` reached the top.

So how can I make `VTabView`'s scroll gesture work when `ScrollView` reached the top?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @DikenShah Sadly, not a clue... I just wondered if this is a bug and may be fixed somehow in the future?